# Cocoa textfield returning null

Tags: objective-c, cocoa, class, methods, textfield

Sorry if it's a bit long but I want to be as descriptive as possible. 
I'm making a test application with several classes and 2 nib files (each class is the owner of one nib). One of the nib files has a textfield, the other has a button. I'm trying to log whatever is inside the text field when the button in the other nib view is pressed, but it returns (null). In one of the classes (ViewClass) I have this:

```
- (IBAction)startAction:(id)sender {
MyClass *anInstance = [[MyClass alloc] init];
NSString *string= [anInstance name];
NSLog(@"startAction logged: %@", string);
```

"Name" is a property of MyClass. What I want to do is have "name" set in the init of MyClass, that way, when anInstance is initialized, the MyClass init method does this:

```
- (id)init {
if ( self = [super init] )   {
    [self setName:[nameInput stringValue]];
    NSLog(@"init value: %@", name);
}
return self;
```

"NameInput" is the textfield. I *thought* this would return whatever was in the textfield, but I get null instead. When I use `setName:@"text"` it gets passed fine, so something is wrong with the text field.

I previously did this with my own getter, and in that case, it didn't return null when the method was called from it's own class, but if it was initialized and called from the other class, then it returned null, I used this:

```
- (NSString *)name {
NSLog(@"nameMethod = %@", [nameInput stringValue]);
return [[[nameInput stringValue] retain] autorelease];
```

This way, I can tell it is all properly set up, but something is happening when I init MyClass from the ViewClass, and try to get "name", that it keeps saying that the text field is null.

Not sure if it helps but the nib with the button belongs to MyView (which is a subclass of NSViewController) and the textfield belongs to MyClass (subclass of NSObject).

Someone suggested the field was not properly linked, but if that was true, it wouldn't have worked when called from it's own class, but it did. Someone else mentioned it might be a problem with the textfield being initialized to nil, so I tried the init thing above. Neither has worked so far.

Thanks for the help.

Answer (score 5):

IBOutlets are not guaranteed to be hooked up until `awakeFromNib`, which is after your objects' init methods have run. You'll need to do your nib setup in `awakeFromNib`.

EDIT NOW THAT I'VE GOTTEN HOME: Sorry, I didn't read carefully enough before. What I said above was true, but there's a deeper problem as well. I see now that you also are dealing with two different objects — one in the nib, one created in code. If you have an object in a nib with an outlet hooked up to an interface element, that doesn't make other objects of that class also have an instance variable referring to the element. Two independently created MyClass instances don't share the same instance variables any more than every NSArray in your program holds the same set of items. If you want to use the instance from the nib, you'll need to use *that* instance.

How you do this is a matter of how you structure your program. There's no simple `[self magicallyGetObjectFromNib]`. Somehow, one object needs to either find the other (say, by knowing the nib's owner) or be told about the other by an object that knows about them both.

Comment: I moved what I had in the init into awakeFromNib and now I don't need my own getter method. But this STILL only works when used in the ViewClass, I tried making *anInstance = (...); [anInstance awakeFromNib]; but when calling it from a different class, it still returns null. The real problem I'm having is getting the ViewClass to tell MyCLass to return the name string in the textfield. But thanks for the help @Chuck.

Comment: I think I understand what you mean, instead of just adding *anInstance various times I'll try to actually make several independent objects that all load the same nib

Comment: @Elbimio: No, you don't want to have them all load the nib over and over again. That will instantiate many copies of the objects in the nib, which will also be different from the one the user is interacting with. You want to get a reference to the one that you already have created.

Comment: I'be been trying this but I still haven't figured it out. I don't know how to make one object find the other

Answer (score 0):

You're in the init routine when you try to extract a value from a field in the same object, and apparently expect it to be initialized.  'Tain't gonna happen.

Comment: Moving it to awakeFromNib still didn't fix the problem of it not working when being called from the other class.

Comment: Is the object instance even connected to the field you want to access?  I'm guessing not.  Check `nameInput` where you reference it -- I'll bet it's nil.